# Difference between versions of "One, Two, Three" (1961)

Tags: alternate-version, one-two-three

The movie [*One, Two, Three* (1961)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055256/) is a Billy Wilder film starring James Cagney. In the film Cagney plays C.R. "Mac" MacNamara, a Coca-Cola executive in West Berlin having been assigned there after a fiasco in the Middle East. Mac wants to eventually become the head of Western European Coca-Cola operations. He is tasked with taking care of the 17-year-old socialite daughter of the company's CEO when she comes to visit Europe. Of course hi-jinks ensue.

In looking at the IMDb page for the film it lists [the following run times](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055256/technical?ref_=tt_dt_spec) for the film:

> 1 hr 44 min (104 min)
>
> 1 hr 48 min (108 min) (UK)
>
> 1 hr 48 min (108 min) (banned) (1962) (Finland)
>
> 1 hr 48 min (108 min) (Ontario) (Canada)

Additionally the [Blu-ray](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XS13R46) of the film lists a runtime of 1 hr 45 min.

Neither IMDb nor Wikipedia list any alternate versions of the film. I am unable to find any information on the reason for the different lengths of this film or if there is a difference between the UK version, the banned Finnish version, or the Canadian version. Can anybody help?

Comment: Funny, you'd expect the country it was banned in to have the shorter version.